# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error message when using a ViewBag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have a controller that cycles through my "Sites" database and gets a value based on their site ID
It looks like this

```
 osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID]; 
 ViewBag.OSITotal = new Dictionary<int, float>();                
 ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID] = osiTotal[s.ID];
```

And then my View looks like this

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID]</td> // Receive error message on this line
 </tr>
}
```

But I receive the error

**The given key was not present in the dictionary**

I have tried doing this to my view

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[1]</td>
 </tr>
}
```

Where I automatically assign the `@ViewBag.OSITotal` a value of "1"
But still receive the same error

Why is this?

Comment: check before retrieving the data by key, using ``@ViewBag.OSITotal.ContainsKey(s.ID)``

Comment: I've never seen a `dictionary` implemented like this before. What are `osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID]`? Usually when adding to a new instance of a `dictionary`, you would add the `key`, followed by the `value`, in the method `.Add` of the dictionary object. Have you debugged your dictionary object to see what is actually in there? Also, there can only be (1) unique key. And @Sajid is correct, you should have a condition to check if the key exists

Comment: @RobScott There is no need to query for a key to exist when doing an assignment. When doing `dictionary[key] = value;`, the `key` will be added automatically if it doesn't exist. Calling the `Add` method requires that the key *does **not*** exist, however.

Comment: @RobScott You stated, *"there can only be (1) unique key"*, which doesn't make sense. All keys must be unique, and the limit of keys is determined only by the amount of available memory (a dictionary can have millions of unique keys).

Comment: @RufusL yes you're correct, i did not read over my comment. It should of read, "each key must be unique". Thanks for correcting that. Also I did not know of the automatic `kvp` addition to the object if the `key` did not exist. I appreciate that insight. Good looking out =)